# Immidate command during MySQL Transaction

Tags: mysql, transactions, payment-processing

During a sign up process, I'm using a Transaction to enclose all the operations involved in the setup of an account so that in the event of a problem they can be rolled back.

The last item that occurs is a billing process so that if payment is successful, the Commit operation is called to finalise the account creation, if say, the user's card is declined, I roll back.

However, I am wondering what the best way is to write a log of the attempted billing to the database without that particular write operation being 'covered' by the transaction protecting the other database operations. Is this possible in MySQL? The log table in question does not depend on any others. Holding on to the data in the application to write it after the rollback operation is somewhat difficult due to legacy payment libraries created before we started using transactions. I'd like to avoid that if MySQL has a solution.

Answer (score 2):

I would not use transactions with that goal in mind. The operations you describe seem to have full right to exist independently.

For example, an invoice has a header and one or more lines. You use a transaction to ensure that you don't store an incomplete invoice in your database because that would be an application error: there's no circumstance in business logic where you have e.g. a line without a header.

However, having an unconfirmed account makes perfect sense from the business logic point of view. The customer will probably prefer to be informed about the situation and be able to provide another payment method rather that start over again.

Furthermore, using a transaction for such a lengthy process requires keeping an open connection with MySQL Server. If you ever need to implement an HTTP interface you'll have to rethink the whole logic.

In short, transactions are a tool to protect against application errors, not a mechanism to implement business logic.